# NSURLErrorDomain trying to reach server on same network from iOS

Tags: ios, node.js

I have a simple NodeJS server set up, serving basic static files (slide show basically), so an `index.html` with some `*.js` files included via `<script...>` and yadda yadda, that's a bit beside the point I think.  I check the server host's IP as part of server start, and it is, for example, `192.168.1.10` with my server running on port 8080.  When I visit `http://192.168.1.10:8080/index.html` from a laptop, it works exactly as expected.  When I visit from my iPhone, I get `NSURLErrorDomain` with no other helpful information.  The server itself logs all HTTP requests (successful or otherwise), and logs correctly for requests from laptops, but logs no request attempts at all when trying from iOS.  I tried using port 80 to be more standard, but this results in the same error.  How can I make it so that my stock basic out-of-the-box iPhone can visit a basic NodeJS server running nothing more complex than `createServer(...` with `require('http')`?

Answer (score 0):

First, there should be a error code alongside with the `NSURLErrorDomain`; you can then check [NSURLErrorDomain error codes description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028769/nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-description)
for more information.

I would guess it has something to do with transport security.

You should either try to use the *HTTPS* secure protocol, or allow arbitrary loads by editing the `Info.plist` file:

> Information Property List -> App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES

or, if you prefer xml:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```